# How to align paragraph using Delphi MSWord automation?

Tags: delphi, ms-word, automation

I want to align a text to center and I have no idea on how to achieve it.
Here is my code:

```
  try
    MsWord := GetActiveOleObject('Word.Application');
  except
    try
      MsWord := CreateOleObject('Word.Application');
      MsWord.Visible := True;
    except
      Exception.Create('Error');
    end;
  end;
  MSWord.Documents.Add;
  MSWord.Selection.Font.Size := 22;
  MSWord.Selection.Font.Bold := true;
  MSWord.Selection.TypeText(#13#10);
  MSWord.Selection.TypeText('I want this to be center-aligned'); 
  ...
  MSWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs('C:\doc2.doc');
```

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: OT: What is the meaning of `Exception.Create('Error')` ? Btw., better catch only `EOleSysError` exceptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MSWord : OleVariant;
begin
  try
    MsWord := GetActiveOleObject('Word.Application');
  except
    try
      MsWord := CreateOleObject('Word.Application');
      MsWord.Visible := True;
    except
      Exception.Create('Error');
    end;
  end;
  MSWord.Documents.Add;
  MSWord.Selection.Font.Size := 22;
  MSWord.Selection.Font.Bold := true;
  MSWord.Selection.TypeText(#13#10);
  MSWord.Selection.TypeText('I want this to be center-aligned');
  MSWord.Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment := wdAlignParagraphCenter;
  MSWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs('C:\doc2.doc');
end;
```

Btw, the way to find the answer yourself is to go into Word, start recording a macro, perform the action, stop recording then edit the macro to see what code Word generates.  Converting that to Delphi is usually fairly trivial if you're using late binding (accessing Word from Delphi via an OleVariant) but can be a bit long winded if you're using early binding, because early binding requires all parameters to be specified, whereas late binding lets you leave most of them out.

Comment: Thanks. It works, and also your advice is very good. I used to do that with Excel and forgot that I can do it with Word too :)

Comment: @user1137313: I've upvoted this, but you should have up-voted this answer too if you like it (you've marked it as accepted, but the upvote helps as well). Just a suggestion.